# "wildcard" function to extract source files in a directory.

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following scenario that I need to implement. I will have to extract all the source files from a specific directory. Hence filter-out certain and compile the rest. I am implementing this case as follows.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(ROOT_DIR)/SRC/*.c)
FILTERED_SOURCES= $(filter-out $(ROOT_DIR)/SRC/File1.c, $(SOURCES))
```

The issue I am facing here is File1.c is not filterd out. I predict the possible reason being the pattern used in the filter-out function is a long path name which has slashes and dots in it. So the questions here are

1. Is it possible to store in **"SOURCES"** just the file-name instead of the entire path
2. Is there anything other than the stated is suspicious in the filter-out command.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (and easy) to reduce `$(SOURCES)` to filenames, but I would like to figure out the cause of this problem. Could you show us `$(ROOT_DIR)`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to print out the value of `SOURCES`? Or maybe, does `$(ROOT_DIR)` contain whitespaces?

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(ROOT_DIR)/SRC/*.c)
$(error $(SOURCES))
```

Personally I would convert everything into absolute paths using [`abspath` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) and then filtering the resulting list.

```
SOURCES          := $(abspath $(wildcard $(ROOT_DIR)/SRC/*.c))
FILTERED_SOURCES := $(filter-out $(abspath $(ROOT_DIR)/SRC/File1.c), $(SOURCES))
```

To go back to use the original `$(ROOT_DIR)` prefix (it is usually optional though) one can use [`patsubst` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
SOURCES          := $(patsubst $(abspath $(ROOT_DIR))%,$(ROOT_DIR)%,$(SOURCES))
FILTERED_SOURCES := $(patsubst $(abspath $(ROOT_DIR))%,$(ROOT_DIR)%,$(FILTERED_SOURCES))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Beta and Eldar!! I worked around my question (1) using a "notdir" function that just extracted me the filename from the complete path.Henceforth I see filter-out to work. I am yet to analyse for the cause of filter-out not happening when using the complete path.

Comment: @Vivek27, did you try the solution with absolute paths? I'm interested if it works or not.